# What does the submat function do in OpenCV-Android?

Tags: android, opencv

What does the submat function do in OpenCV-Android?
I am trying to understand a code that I found that really does the functionality I am looking for, which I perfectly understand the code except for the 'Submat' function since in the documentation I cannot find its detail of the parameters

```
Mat zoomCorner = rgba.Submat(0, rows / 2 - rows / 10, 0, cols / 2 - cols / 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mat` object in OpenCV use reference counting approach.

`Mat` has reference to buffer and buffer parameters.

When you use `submat()`, you get new `Mat` that shares image data buffer with original `Mat`.

You need to copy `ROI` to new `Mat` with `Mat::copyTo()` method and make all calculations with  `submat()` copy.